# How to set dynamic dialog box position by CSS?

Tags: jquery, css-position, division

I have a dynamic dialog box (div/popup) which opens on the click event. My problem is if the clickable element at the bottom of the windows screen my dynamic dialog box shows under the screen, but I want to show it above the screen in this case.

Please check the current scenarios in below image-

[image]

But I want to show this dynamic div above the screen. Like below image-

[image]

I am working on C#/Angular JS.

Answer (score 0):

well you can try this jQuery code:

```
$("#threeDots").click(function(){
 $("#dynamicdialog").css({
  position: fixed,
  bottom: 0,
  right: 0,
  width: 300px
 })
 $("#dynamicdialog").show();
})
```

Comment: it's working partially . Means I am able to show the dialog box above the screen, but it's happening for all the sections. I only want's it for the section which is at the bottom of the screen and for rest of the sections it should show as existing.